# Rsync from Ubuntu to Synology fails when created as task

Tags: rsync

I have a Synology which is used as a backup system for my Ubuntu server.
I've created a script where my Synology will rsync via ssh from my Ubuntu Server to itself.

```
rsync -avrhv --no-o --no-g --no-perms --delete -e "ssh -p 1433 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" raf@192.168.1.3:/mnt/raid/0/Movies/ /volume1/Movies
```

The script works when I run it in CLI. But when I add it as a task in my Synology I get the following output. It is run as the same user as in CLI. So permissions should be fine...

```
receiving incremental file list
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 4096 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 4096 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
rsync: mkdir "/volume1/Movies\#015" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(689) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Comment: Could a carriage return character (octal `015`) have crept in to the end of your command? For example if you copy+pasted it via Windows

Comment: @steeldriver my god. THX!